# Debezium mySql connecter not able to capture insert and updater operation

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I am trying to implemnt CDC piline with Debezium mysql connecter and kafkal
But Source connecter not able to pusblish event for insert and update operation in table... Schema changes are reflecting in kafka Topic

i have check bin log is ebabled

here are my Source connecter configuration

```
    "name": "user_source_v6",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "host....",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "test",
        "database.password": "test",
        "database.server.id": "119",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver19",
        "database.whitelist": "crowdsource",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "user_source_v6",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "host...:9092",
        "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "true"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there logs that indicate the problem? Either from Debezium or the database?

Comment: Seems like similar problem I am struggling with at the moment https://stackoverflow.com/q/71949581/1065468

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is observed when CDC on database/table is enabled to capture limited operations.

Re-enable CDC on the table with all operations enabled. (C,U,D)